# How to remove duplicates in a SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that is built for an specific filter that I want to re-structure it to provide me an output for all records, but it is creating duplicate sum values.

The initial query I have is as follows:

```
SELECT  
    CustomerNo, 
    (SELECT SUM(Amount) 
     FROM DetailedCustLedgEntry DLE 
     WHERE  
         DLE.PostingDate <= '2019-12-16' AND 
         DLE.[Entry Type] In (1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,17) AND 
         DLE.CustLedgerEntryNo = CLE.EntryNo) as TotalAmount,
    --Amt Modifer 1
    (SELECT SUM(ClosedByAmount) 
     FROM CustLedgerEntry 
     WHERE 
        "Closed by EntryNo" = CLE.EntryNo AND 
        PostingDate <= '2019-12-16') as AmtModifer1,
    --Amt Modifier 2
    (SELECT SUM(ClosedByAmount * -1) 
     FROM CustLedgerEntry 
     WHERE 
        EntryNo = CLE."Closed by EntryNo" AND 
        PostingDate <= '2019-12-16') as AmtModifer2
FROM 
    CustLedgerEntry CLE 
WHERE 
    CustomerNo = '104421' AND 
    "Open"=1 AND 
    Branch='D--HE-001' AND 
    PostingDate<='2019-12-17'
```

The query above filters by CustomerNo = '104421', but I want to be able to see all customers.

I have created joints as follows:

```
SELECT  
    CLE.CustomerNo,
    SUM(DLE.Amount) as TotalAmount,
    SUM(CLE_AM1.ClosedByAmount) as AmtModifer1,
    SUM(CLE_AM2.ClosedByAmount * -1) as AmtModifer2
INTO
    #TempCLE
FROM 
    CustLedgerEntry CLE 
LEFT JOIN
    DetailedCustLedgEntry DLE ON DLE.CustLedgerEntryNo = CLE.EntryNo
LEFT JOIN
    CustLedgerEntry CLE_AM1 ON CLE_AM1."Closed by EntryNo" = CLE.EntryNo
LEFT JOIN
    CustLedgerEntry CLE_AM2 ON CLE_AM2.EntryNo = CLE."Closed by EntryNo"
WHERE 
    CLE."Open" = 1 AND 
    CLE.Branch = 'D--HE-001' AND 
    CLE.PostingDate <= '2019-12-17' and
    DLE.PostingDate <= '2019-12-16' AND 
    DLE.[Entry Type] IN (1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,17)
GROUP BY
    CLE.CustomerNo
```

The problem I have is that the `TotalAmount` seems to duplicate the output (like, sum the value twice, instead of 2 I see 4)

If I remove the joints for CLE_AM1 and CLE_AM2 the duplicates. I'm guessing the problem is in these joints, but I don't see how they should be build instead

```
LEFT JOIN
    "Bobcat Bensheim GmbH$Cust_ Ledger Entry" CLE_AM1 ON CLE_AM1."Closed by Entry No_" = CLE."Entry No_"
LEFT JOIN
    "Bobcat Bensheim GmbH$Cust_ Ledger Entry" CLE_AM2 ON CLE_AM2."Entry No_" = CLE."Closed by Entry No_"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of SQL? Window functions might be what you're looking for.  Can you provide an example schema and data?

Comment: I'm wondering if the customer number or something else appears in one of the tables more than once, and this is creating the issue.  Can you try "SELECT distinct (CLE.CustomerNo)"?  Maybe also with some of the other variables?